# Adding caption with minipages to \includepdf figure page

Tags: minipage, pdfpages

I have a pdf file with `\includepdf` as a latex page.
I am trying to add an **caption** to it.

I tried using `minipage`, but the capture shows up randomly on the graphic:

```
\begin{minipage}[c]{1.5\textwidth}
\includepdf[pages={1}, scale=1]{fusion_app.pdf}
\captionof{figure}{Caption for image}
\end{minipage}
\includepdf[pages=2-6, scale=1]{fusion_app.pdf}
```

Is there a way for me to put it at the top or bottom and squeeze the image in the area below or above it?

Comment: Use `\includegraphics` rather than `\includepdf`. Please post a compilable example if you need more help. I don't see how that code can possibly do what you say.

Comment: Hi, I can't do that because my figure is multiple pages long. I converted it to a multi page pdf first and added it with \includepdf, this way each page is shown in consequent pages.

Comment: `\includepdf` includes complete pages. It always starts and ends with a new page.

Comment: I don't know any other way to "automatically" put my long figures in multiple pages. I can put caption in the way I have written as well, it just shows up in a random place overlaying the figure. Can't I rescale the image and keep the caption in a conventional place? Either top or bottom?

Comment: I'm astonished this doesn't just give you errors. (It will certainly give you bad boxes.) It makes no sense to `\includepdf` in a `minipage`. If you want to include something on the same page as the included PDF, you can use the `pagecommand` or the `picture` options. You can't put the caption 'in the conventional place' because that place is *relative* to the preceding content. But there is nothing before the caption on this page. The included PDF is not on this page, so far as LaTeX is concerned when typesetting it.

Comment: `\includegraphics` includes an image in the flow of typesetting i.e. at this point. Here. `\includepdf` doesn't do that. It just changes what happens when the page is shipped out. You can't combine it with content from the regular flow of typesetting in any meaningful way. At least, that's how I understand it. The only reason it is on the same page at all is because the `minipage` can't be broken. But it can't keep the PDF together with the caption because they aren't together in the first place.

Comment: You still haven't provided compilable code. Why can't you include the first page with `\includegraphics` since that seems to be the only one needing a caption?

Comment: It compiles for me. Ok, I added the first one with \includegraphics and yes that worked (In practice, it would be better to add the last one with \includegraphics and the caption shows under the whole figure) -However- it is impossible to get it seamlessly match the consequent pages of the figure. I have tried multiple scales and widths, it looks terrible. The reason why I use \includepdf, I don't have to trim the figure myself, it is an interconnected image so it doesn't look seamless like it does with \includepdf

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The only reason the first page looks different in my example is because I made room for the caption. And why can't you add the last with `\includegraphics`? I only said the first because that was your example. Obviously you can do the reverse if that's what you need. Or else, as I say in my answer, use `pagecommand` or `picture`. That's a bit more fiddly, but perfectly doable.

Comment: Note that `\includepdf` is just wrapping `\includegraphics` anyway. So you are essentially treating the images in the same way.

Comment: Look, I appreciate but I have a figure which is interconnected with diagrams and arrows and transitions, so it doesn't look seamless when I add one of them with \includegraphics. What you said made sense in theory but I tried it and it doesn't look seamless. And my code compiles for me, I compile with pdfLaTeX

Comment: You see the yellow page in your example? It looks different than other pages right? When the figure has connections, the difference looks much greater and doesn't connect seamlessly

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @dusa The yellow page only looks different because ***you asked how to 'squeeze' it to fit the caption***. Obviously, if you make it smaller, it will be a different size. So you have a choice: don't 'squeeze' it (option 1) or 'squeeze' only it (option 2) or 'squeeze' all pages to match (option 3). I don't understand what you think a solution would look like here. You seem to want obviously incompatible things.

Answer (score 7):

## Option 1

Use `\includegraphics` for the page which needs the caption. It doesn't matter if this is the first page or not. Here, I exclude the first two pages of a seven page PDF, add a caption when including page three with `\includegraphics`, and then use `\includepdf` to include the next three pages. But you can mix and match as you please.

Since we don't want the included page three to float away, we can't use `figure` or another environment which supports `\caption`. However, the `caption` package provides `\captionof` for such cases. (Alternatively, load `captionof`, which provides *just* this facility.)

I've centred the included page three, which is likely what you want. If not, omit `\centering`.

You can't include multiple pages at once with `\includegraphics`. If you need text repeated on multiple pages, use the `pagecommand` or `picture` keys provided by `pdfpages`. But I gather this is not required from your non-working example code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages,caption,geometry}
\begin{document}
\verb|mypages| is a 7 page document.
The first page is red, the second orange, the third yellow and so on through the rainbow.

\newgeometry{scale=1}
\thispagestyle{empty}
{%
  \centering
  \includegraphics[page=3,scale=.95]{mypages}
  \captionof{figure}{Page 3 in the original.}
  \par
}
\includepdf[pages={4-6}]{mypages}
\restoregeometry

This should be back to normal.
\end{document}
```

[image: example inclusion]

## Option 2

Use `picturecommand`, `picturecommand*` or `pagecommand`. `picturecommand*` affects only the first page. The others affect all pages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages,geometry,calc}
\begin{document}
\verb|mypages| is a 7 page document.
The first page is red, the second orange, the third yellow and so on through the rainbow.

\includepdf[pages=3-6,scale=.9,picturecommand*={\put (\LenToUnit{.05\paperwidth},20) {Page 3 in the original.};}]{mypages}

This should be back to normal.
\end{document}
```

[image: with picturecommand*]

Note the only reason these are now uniform is that I've scaled all pages by the same amount. You could equally do this with Option 1.

Comment: I appreciate but I have a figure which is interconnected with diagrams and arrows and transitions, so it doesn't look seamless when I add one of them with \includegraphics. What you said made sense in theory but I tried it and it doesn't look seamless. And my code compiles for me, I compile with pdfLaTeX

Comment: @dusa It compiles. Surprising, I think. But it does compile. The problem is it doesn't make any sense. You can't place the caption relative to the image.

Comment: @dusa You can see above but, since your desiderata are, as far as I can tell, that you want to do what cannot possibly be done, I'm sure it will be no more satisfactory than the first option.

Answer (score 0):

@dusa
I had a similar issue and I was able to fix it like that

### single caption

```latex
    % include PDF with caption
    \newgeometry{scale=1}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    {%
        \raggedleft
        \includegraphics[page=1,width=.9\linewidth,left]{/path/to/pdf}
        \captionof{figure}{What you see is what you get}
        \label{fig:graphic}
        \par
        \clearpage
        \includegraphics[page=2,width=.9\linewidth,right]{/path/to/pdf}
        \par
        \par
        \clearpage
    }
    \restoregeometry
```

### one caption per page

```latex
    % include PDF with caption
    \newgeometry{scale=1}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    {%
        \centering
        \includegraphics[page=1,width=.9\linewidth]{/path/to/pdf}
        \captionof{figure}{What you see is what you get 1/2}
        \label{fig:graphic}
        \par
        \clearpage
        \centering
        \includegraphics[page=2,width=.9\linewidth]{/path/to/pdf}
    %   \includegraphics[page=2,width=.9\linewidth,right]{/path/to/pdf}
        \captionof{figure}{What you see is what you get 2/2}
        \par
        \clearpage
    }
    \restoregeometry
```

I would then always refer to the first page of the figure, thus only one label